# Dynamically adding TextView causes null point exception

Tags: android, textview

I want to add textview dynamically. When i try to do this iam getting null point exception

this is my code snippet:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View vs = (View) Inflater.inflate(R.layout.serverd_details, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) vs.findViewById(R.id.SerText);
textView.setText("server details");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.addView(textView, p);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Post the error log from logcat

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout like this

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.Id.your_layout_ID)
```

or

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) vs.findViewById(R.id.SerText);
```

is SerText ID is placed in your XML Layout

Answer (score 0):

Hello Karthick Pandiyan,

I think you are doing well but after viewing your code, i want to suggest you

Use below code.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setText("server details");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout.addView(textView, p);
```

I think it will work.